# How to scrape dates of News Site

Tags: python, html, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap the news website with news that are valid of a certain date.
The output of the function return :

```
<li class="meta-data"><time data-datetime="relative" datetime="2022-01-30T08:56:09Z" title="2022-01-30T08:56:09Z">January 30, 2022 08:56</time></li>
```

How can I only print the Date time only?
Printing i.text dont seem to work.

Below is the code.

> ```
> import requests
> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
> import datetime as datetime
> from datetime import timedelta
> import pandas as pd
> pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None)
> pd.set_option('max_colwidth',None)
>
> def okx_scrap():
>
>     b = []
>     url = 'https://www.okex.com/support/hc/en-us/sections/360000030652-Latest-Announcements'
>     page = requests.get(url)
>     soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
>     small_soup = soup.find_all(class_ = "article-list-link")
>     url_1st = 'https://www.okex.com/support'
>
>         #Getting Yesterday's Date
>
>     
>
>
>     for i in small_soup:
>         full_url = url_1st +(i['href'])
>         page2 = requests.get(full_url)
>         soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.content,'html.parser')
>         small_soup2 = soup2.find_all('li', {'class': 'meta-data'})
>         #print(small_soup2)
>         for i in small_soup2:
>             print(i)
>
>             
>
>    
>
> okx_scrap()
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `find_all` but `find` because there is only one entry in each page and extract `time` markup and not `li`:

```
def okx_scrap():

    b = []
    url = 'https://www.okex.com/support/hc/en-us/sections/360000030652-Latest-Announcements'
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
    small_soup = soup.find_all(class_ = "article-list-link")
    url_1st = 'https://www.okex.com/support'

        #Getting Yesterday's Date

    for i in small_soup:
        full_url = url_1st +(i['href'])
        page2 = requests.get(full_url)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.content,'html.parser')
        print(soup2.find('time')['datetime'])
```

Output:

```
>>> okx_scrap()
2022-01-30T08:56:09Z
2022-01-29T05:41:18Z
2022-01-28T10:15:02Z
2022-01-28T07:29:11Z
2022-01-28T06:45:48Z
2022-01-28T03:13:18Z
...
```

Comment: thank you, i was blindly copying the codes i use for other websites it seems and yes I should have done a 'find'

Comment: @leehongwei. So does it work?

Comment: yes sir ! It works. The plan for me is to use the date as a validator for me to confirm that the news is recent enough for me so i can proceed to scrap the full_url.

thanks alot Corralien!

Comment: sorry, didnt know i should click on the accept, have done that. thx

Answer (score 0):

Considering `i` as a string (if not typecase the variable `i` to a string using built in method `i = str(i)`)

```
i = str(i)
i = i.split("><")[1]
i = i.split("datetime=")[2]
i = i.split("\"")[1]

print(i)
# 2022-01-30T08:56:09Z
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex:

```
import re

string = '<li class="meta-data"><time data-datetime="relative" datetime="2022-01-30T08:56:09Z" title="2022-01-30T08:56:09Z">January 30, 2022 08:56</time></li>'

datetime= r"(\d{1,4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}Z)"

output = re.findall(datetime, string)

#output:

['2022-01-30T08:56:09Z', '2022-01-30T08:56:09Z']
```